# OSGI: DS and component factories issues

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

What I need is to get new instance of service every time when some consumer needs this service + using CDI. I've read a lot of articles and I can't find the answer to 2 my questions.

1. If we use factories, why in service consumer we call factory (http://www.rpgnextgen.com/wiki/doku.php?id=component_factory ) and after that we get reference to service. I mean

   ```
   // get factory
   ComponentFactory factory = (ComponentFactory) context.getService(serviceReferences[0]);
   // get instance
   ComponentInstance instance = factory.newInstance(null);
   ```

Is there no way to set factory with certain interface and in service consumer call service when osgi inside calls the factory?

2. If in service consumer we call factory then why we mark service as component when de facto factory is component?

The problem is that without factory I do @Inject @OsgiService (javase) or`@OSGiService (javaee)` and I can use different filters and code is very clear. Using component factory I (as I understand) loose this ability.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your questions.

Comment: @BJ Hargrave Thank you for your time. I will try to explain. We have three entity: service consumer, component factory and component. As I understood if I want to get component in service consumer then in service consumer I must call the factory.newInstance(). I can't understand the logic. For example in javafx you just set somefactory with some interface and after that forget about this factory as it is "auto" used. I can't understand why in osgi I should call factory, instead of getting reference to component via osgi (it osgi must call the factory). Could I explain my first question?

Comment: There is no requirement to use ComponentFactory.

Comment: @BJ Hargrave Could you just give a hint what I should read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComponentFactory` exists for consumers that *want* to use a factory, because they want to control the lifecycle of the individual components. For example, if they want to create an instance of the component for every web request.

If you don't want to use `ComponentFactory`... then don't.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I need for every consumer new instance of component. That's why (as I understand) I have to use component Factory. However, I can't understand why I can't register my factory in osgi and get the service in consumer without calling the factory. The problem is that without factory I do `@Inject @OsgiService` (javase) or `@OSGiService` (javaee) and calling the component factory I loose this ability.

Comment: No, `ComponentFactory` is for a different use case. If you want to use the prototype scope for services then you will have to wait until DS supports this, when version 1.3 is released.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't wait so long. So, can I use osgi services (new instance for every consumer) with CDI -`@Inject @OsgiService` ?

Comment: I can't answer that as I don't use CDI (I'm not a masochist...).

Comment: Please note that Neil is the closest you can get to an authoritative figure in this regard ([tag:osgi], [tag:apache-felix]).

Comment: @AdamArold That's kind but not really true. I know a lot about OSGi but not as much as, say, BJ Hargrave who actually works on the specs and is CTO of the OSGi Alliance!

Comment: @NeilBartlett I've read your book and I think it is more than enough to answer these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0):

> I need for every consumer new instance of component.

I haven't tried yet, but according to the documentation when using *PAX-CDI* and an *OSGi v6* container then the prototype scope should do what you need:

```
@OsgiServiceProvider
@PrototypeScoped
public class MyService implements SomeService{
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! The problem is that I have to create osgi services via DS, as the same bundle must be used both in javase (pax+weld) and glassfish (fighter fish). I know about the solution you provided, but it works only for javase.

Answer (score 0):

OSGi services in are special types of beans in CDI. Compare them to EJBs, you can use CDI to inject references to the different types of EJBs, but the components will have their own lifecycle. The same goes for OSGi services; their life cycle is not controlled by CDI. CDI just injects references to those services.

This means CDI factories can't be used with OSGi services. Just like you can't use CDI factories with EJBs. There is not really a way to create an OSGi service instance per injection point, so there's no workaround either.

If you require this kind of model: You have to create a factory mechanism yourself.